# How can I plug my own TZ data?

Tags: java, jsr310

I've seen [ResourceZoneRulesDataProvider](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/time/calendar/zone/ResourceZoneRulesDataProvider.java) which loads the TZ data via ClassLoader.getResource. But how can I instruct ThreeTen to load my own TZ data instead, say from a shared file system unrelated to my app's CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, ResourceZoneRulesDataProvider is hard coded in ZoneRulesGroup. This obviously won't be the final solution, but was a suitable design right now to keep things working. If you need to change this now, you'll need to edit the source of ZoneRulesGroup.

Answer (score 0):

If this is because of the recent licensing issue, then read: [Time zone database rebooted](http://blog.joda.org/2011/10/time-zone-database-rebooted.html)

Comment: Thanks, but it's unrelated to that.